# Confirm DropDownList selected value

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to show the user a confirm dialog when he tries to change the selected item of a DropDownList. If the selection is confirmed i want to execute some server side code.

Say, DDL has values 1 and 2.

- Value 1 is selected (default).
- The user selects Value 2. A confirm dialog appears.
- If the user selects 'Yes', then the selected item changes.  Some server side code must be executed.
- If the user selects 'No' then the selected item is reverted back to Value 1. No server side code executed.

I'm having a lot of trouble with this one, since DDL has few events to use.

So far i got

```
this.MyDropDown.Attributes["onChange"] = @"return confirm('Are you sure?');";
```

and a `event handler` for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the DDL for the server side code.

But i'm having trouble with the fact that i can't neither stop (or revert) the item being changed nor the `SelectedIndexChanged` event being fired.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not triggering the server side event is because you're wiping out the built-in webforms event handler that would trigger the post back. As for reverting the value, you'll need to save it and then reload it.

add this javascript function

```
function handleChange(opt) {
    if (!confirm('are you sure')) {
        opt.selectedIndex = opt.oldIndex;
    }
    else {
        __doPostBack('MyDropDown','')
    }
}
```

and set the client side events like so

```
this.MyDropDown.Attributes["onChange"] = "handleChange(this)";
this.MyDropDown.Attributes["onFocus"] = "this.oldIndex = this.selectedIndex";
```

Comment: Terrific!!! This is exactly what I needed. Make sure you turn off AutoPostBack = True when using this because the else clause does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is complete solution, as i have already used it. Just refer the following instructions:

```
// Paste it in Aspx file
function handleChange(opt) {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        opt.selectedIndex = opt.oldIndex;
    }
    else {
        __doPostBack('MyDropDown','')
    }
}
```

Paste this in **Page Load** event outside **IsPostBack**:

```
this.MyDropDown.Attributes["onChange"] = "handleChange(this)";
this.MyDropDown.Attributes["onFocus"] = "this.oldIndex = this.selectedIndex";
```

**Note:** Set AutoPostBack Proerty False of Dropdownlist.